# Complex Access query runs slowly, chunks CPU, and doesn't return expected results

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Here is my access query that I have.  Every value that I return is required (unfortunately).  The worst part of this query, however.  Is that it sometimes misses rows that fit the criteria in the WHERE clause.  Every optimization I tried to make does not help, or cannot be done in Access (knowing SQL).  The WHERE clause, as you can see, checks between three date fields.  Here's the tricky part.  For every one row of information in Inventory Masterfile, there are five rows in Inventory Stores (one for each "BranchID") and the Date columns I'm checking against in the where clause, could have the date updated in any one of those five rows, to the one row in Inventory Masterfile.  Does anyone have any suggestions at all that could help me?  I've been debugging for weeks and am at the end of my wits on this one.

```
SELECT a.Item1,im.Secondary,im.Description,im.Author_Artist,im.RetailPrice,im.CatalogID,im.Publisher, im.Binding,im.PubDate,im.Grouping,im.CategoryId,im.Alt_Category,

(SELECT MAX(ls.OnHand) FROM [Inventory Store] ls WHERE (ls.Item1 = a.Item1 AND ls.BranchID = 5)) AS 1Stock,

(SELECT MAX(ls.OnHand) FROM [Inventory Store] ls WHERE (ls.Item1 = a.Item1 AND ls.BranchID = 3)) AS 2Stock,

(SELECT MAX(ls.OnHand) FROM [Inventory Store] ls WHERE (ls.Item1 = a.Item1 AND ls.BranchID = 4)) AS 3Stock,

(SELECT MAX(ls.Maximum) FROM [Inventory Store] ls WHERE (ls.Item1 = a.Item1 AND ls.BranchID = 4)) AS Maximum,

(SELECT MAX(ls.LastSold1) FROM [Inventory Store] ls WHERE (ls.Item1 = a.Item1)) AS LastSold1,

(SELECT MAX(ls.LastUpdate) FROM [Inventory Store] ls WHERE (ls.Item1 = a.Item1)) AS LastUpdate,

(SELECT MAX(ls.LastReceived) FROM [Inventory Store] ls WHERE (ls.Item1 = a.Item1)) AS LastReceived

FROM [Inventory Store] AS a

INNER JOIN [Inventory Masterfile] im ON a.Item1 = im.Item1

WHERE (a.LastSold1 > #6/12/2012# OR a.LastUpdate > #6/12/2012# OR a.LastReceived > #6/12/2012#)

GROUP BY a.Item1, im.Secondary, im.Description, im.Author_Artist, im.RetailPrice, 
im.CatalogID,im.Publisher, im.Binding,im.PubDate,im.Grouping,im.CategoryId,im.Alt_Category
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you have subqueries and they are slow.

```
SELECT a.item1,
       im.secondary,
       im.description,
       im.author_artist,
       im.retailprice,
       im.catalogid,
       im.publisher,
       im.binding,
       im.pubdate,
       im.grouping,
       im.categoryid,
       im.alt_category,
       z.[1stock],
       y.[2stock],
       x.[3stock],
       w.mmaximum,
       v.mlastsold1,
       u.mlastupdate,
       t.mlastreceived
FROM   (((((((([inventory store] AS a
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT ls.item1,
                                 Max(ls.onhand) AS [1Stock]
                          FROM   [inventory store] ls
                          WHERE  ls.branchid = 5
                          GROUP  BY ls.item1) AS z
                      ON a.item1 = z.item1)
              LEFT JOIN (SELECT ls.item1,
                                Max(ls.onhand) AS [2Stock]
                         FROM   [inventory store] ls
                         WHERE  ls.branchid = 3
                         GROUP  BY ls.item1) AS y
                     ON a.item1 = y.item1)
             LEFT JOIN (SELECT ls.item1,
                               Max(ls.onhand) AS [3Stock]
                        FROM   [inventory store] ls
                        WHERE  ls.branchid = 4
                        GROUP  BY ls.item1) AS x
                    ON a.item1 = x.item1)
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT ls.item1,
                              Max(ls.maximum) AS [mMaximum]
                       FROM   [inventory store] ls
                       WHERE  ls.branchid = 4
                       GROUP  BY ls.item1) AS w
                   ON a.item1 = w.item1)
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT ls.item1,
                             Max(ls.lastsold1) AS mLastSold1
                      FROM   [inventory store] ls
                      GROUP  BY ls.item1) AS v
                  ON a.item1 = v.item1)
          LEFT JOIN (SELECT ls.item1,
                            Max(ls.lastupdate) AS mLastUpdate
                     FROM   [inventory store] ls
                     GROUP  BY ls.item1) AS u
                 ON a.item1 = u.item1)
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT ls.item1,
                           Max(ls.lastreceived) AS mLastReceived
                    FROM   [inventory store] ls
                    GROUP  BY ls.item1) AS t
                ON a.item1 = t.item1)
        LEFT JOIN [inventory masterfile] im
               ON a.item1 = im.item1)
WHERE  ( a.lastsold1 > #2012/6/12#
          OR a.lastupdate > #2012/6/12#
          OR a.lastreceived > #2012/6/12# )
GROUP  BY a.item1,
          im.secondary,
          im.description,
          im.author_artist,
          im.retailprice,
          im.catalogid,
          im.publisher,
          im.binding,
          im.pubdate,
          im.grouping,
          im.categoryid,
          im.alt_category,
          z.[1stock],
          y.[2stock],
          x.[3stock],
          w.mmaximum,
          v.mlastsold1,
          u.mlastupdate,
          t.mlastreceived
```

Comment: I had to add       z.[1stock],
       y.[2stock],
       x.[3stock],
       w.mmaximum,
to the grouping, but otherwise WOWOWOWOWOWOW.  I had no idea subqueries did that!  Thank you!
       v.mlastsold1,
       u.mlastupdate,
       t.mlastreceived

Comment: Oops. yes, I have added the fields above. Derived tables can be fast, sub queries are slow, see http://forum.lessthandot.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=17061&p=78214&hilit=subqueries#p78214 it is about sql server, but also relevant here.